# CakePHP 3.0 Flash Message

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 2.0, I can check if there a flash message by using

```
if($session->check('Message.flash')){...}
```

I understand that in CakePHP 3.0, I read the [doc](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#checking-request-conditions) that I can check if there a flash message by using

**Layout**

```
echo $this->Flash->render('auth');
```

**Template/Users/login**

```
echo $this->Flash->render();
if($this->request->is('flash')){...}else{...}
```

But in my view is when I added the above condition is not showing anything. My controller code is below

```
$this->Flash->error('The email address and/or password you specified are not correct.');
return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users', 'action' => 'login'));
```

Can anyone point to me what else is missing? I want to check if a flash message is shown in CakePHP 3.0. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you want to check if there's a flash message? Why not just use the code to display it if it's there? Also, is('flash') would be used in a Controller, and is used to detect if the user-agent generating the request is Flash, not what you're using it for.

Comment: Thanks for response. I would like to show a default message in the login page. If there a flash message, I would like to replace the default message with the flash message. Therefore, I would like to do a condition check at the view. I can achieve that in CakePHP 2.0 though.

Comment: Typically you would check the conditional in the Controller or elsewhere, and then set the flash message based on the outcome. Then you just show the flash message where you want regardless. Best to keep logic out of your views and where it belongs.

Answer (score 1):

Usually what I do, I create a custom flash message for all exceptions.

In Template/Elemen/Flash place custom_error.ctp

In your controller:

```
$this->Flash->customError('A message... ',['key' => 'cutom_error_key',]);
```

And in the view/template:

```
$this->Flash->render('custom_error_key');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still do it in CakePHP 2 way that is read this value from session. You can access session in layout through request object.

```
$session = $this->request->session();
if ($session->check('Flash.flash')) {...}
```

Or if you want to check is there "auth" key message:

```
if ($session->read('Flash.flash.key' == 'auth')) {...}
```

This is how session array now looks with Flash, if you wanna do something else:

```
[
    ...
    'Flash' => [
        'flash' => [
            'message' => 'The page has been saved.',
            'key' => 'flash',
            'element' => 'Flash/success',
            'params' => []
        ]
    ]
    ...
]
```

Answer (score -1):

In Controller action

```
$this->Flash->success(__('The data has been saved.'));
```

OR

```
$this->Flash->error(__('The data could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
```

Put anywhere in View or Layout file

```
<?php
$class = 'message';
if (!empty($params['class'])) {
    $class .= ' ' . $params['class'];
}
?>
<div class="<?= h($class) ?>"><?= h($message) ?></div>
```