# PHPUnit testing a flash message with a key and parameters in CakePHP 3.5

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

CakePHP Version: 3.5.17 
PHPUnit: 6.5.8

**The message in the users controller add action:**

```
$this->Flash->my_message_to_test('', [
    'key' => 'message',
        'params' => [
        'p1' => __('SUCCESS - The '),
        'p2' => __($user->role),
        'p3' => $user->first_name,
        'p4' => $user->last_name,
        'p5' => __('has been created.')
    ]
]);
```

**How I render it in my users add view:** 
$this->Flash->render('message')

---

I've searched for an example but couldn't find that much information about it but I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963296/cakephp-3-0-flash-message) post which helped me construct a unit test as the following with a bit of trial and error:

**$this->assertSession('SUCCESS - The Superuser Abc Def has been created.', 'Flash.flash.key' == 'message.0.message');**

When I ran the test the cli provided the following error:

**Error - InvalidArgumentException: Invalid parameter , should be dot separated path or array.**

With this information I have tried numerous ways to reconstruct this assertion but still no luck.

**My question/request:**

Could someone help me construct this assertion to enable a pass?

Thanks Z.

---

@ndm,

On the basis of what I learnt I've had a go at reconstructing the assertion by amending the path. Please see below for my attempts.

**ATTEMPT 1:**
// Try using concatenation to append the key value to the path because the current path uses it.

```
$this->assertSession('SUCCESS - The Superuser Abc Def has been created.', 'Flash.flash.key.message.0.message');
```

**ATTEMPT 2:**
// Try adding to the current path.

```
$this->assertSession('SUCCESS - The Superuser Abc Def has been created.', 'Flash.flash/key/message.0.message');

$this->assertSession('SUCCESS - The Superuser Abc Def has been created.', 'Flash.flash?key=message.0.message');
```

**ATTEMPT 3:**
// Try defining the key value as message.

```
$this->assertSession('SUCCESS - The Superuser Abc Def has been created.', "Flash.flash.'key'=>'message'.".'0.message');
```

**ATTEMPT 4:**
// Try using an array to define the key value as message. (Simulate the controllers definition method)

```
$this->assertSession('SUCCESS - The Superuser Abc Def has been created.', "Flash.flash.['key'=>'message'].".'0.message');

$this->assertSession('SUCCESS - The Superuser Abc Def has been created.', "Flash.flash['key'=>'message'].".'0.message');
```

**Summary**

Unfortunately all my attempts result in the following cli failure:

Failure asserting that null matches expected 'SUCCESS ...'

I really can't think of anything else to try which make sense to me. If it's showing null it would mean that the path is not pointing to the correct resource which means that the construction of the path is incorrect?

And if that's correct I'm not sure what else to try to construct that path correctly?

---

@Greg Schmidt, thanks for your comment. I still can't get it to recognise the key? I still get Failure asserting that null matches expected 'SUCCESS ...'

In my usersCorporateController I use the following code which works and I got from the cookbooks testing section.

**usersCorporateController - Register action**

```
$this->Flash->error(__('Please correct the errors!'));
```

**usersCorporate - Register view**

```
$this->Flash->render()
```

**usersCorporateControllerRegisterErrorMessageTest - Register test**

```
$this->enableRetainFlashMessages();

$this->assertSession('Please correct the errors!', 'Flash.flash.0.message');
```

And this works.

Then I go to create a test for my usersController add action. The difference being this message uses a key and is declared in the view with the below. (Please find code at top of post)

**users - Add view**

```
$this->Flash->render('message') // Different
```

I know my add action test works and I add the following to the test.

**usersControllerAddTest - Add test**

```
$this->enableRetainFlashMessages();

$this->assertSession('SUCCESS - The Superuser Abc Def has been created.', 'Flash.flash.0.message');
```

And I get this error in the cli:

Failure asserting that null matches expected 'SUCCESS ...'

And I think this is correct because it hasn't got any way to differentiate between the messages, how will it know how to reference the message with a key?

And thats when I start to search for an answer and start trying to construct the assertion with a reference to the key.

You pointed out debugging the session which I never did so I'm going to learn how to run the test from the browser and utilize the debug kit, see what that reveals.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**Another Attempt:**

I haven't got a solution but I thought I'd write this to help anyone in the future who is attempting to test a flash message with a key.

I started again and followed the cookbooks example to the letter. I referenced the following information in the Cookbook:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/flash.html

Within this section the following is detailed.

```
// In your Controller
$this->Flash->success('The user has been saved', [
    'key' => 'positive',
    'params' => [
        'name' => $user->name,
        'email' => $user->email
    ]
]);

// In your View
<?= $this->Flash->render('positive') ?>

// In src/Template/Element/Flash/success.ctp
<div id="flash-<?= h($key) ?>" class="message-info success">
    <?= h($message) ?>: <?= h($params['name']) ?>, <?= h($params['email']) ?>.
</div>
```

On this basis I have the following code in my app.

```
// Users controller add action.
$this->Flash->success('The user has been saved', [
    'key' => 'positive',
    'params' => [
        'firstname' => $user->first_name,
        'lastname' => $user->last_name
     ]
]);

// Users Add View.
<?= $this->Flash->render('positive') ?>

// In src/Template/Element/Flash/success.ctp
<div id="flash-<?= h($key) ?>" class="message-info success">
    <?= h($message) ?>: <?= h($params['firstname' ]) ?>, <?= h($params['lastname' ]) ?>.
</div>
```

And this works, when a user is added the message with the parameters is displayed. The message displayed is:

The user has been saved: Abc, Def.

**The test result:**

The assertion in the test is constructed as detailed below:

$this->assertSession('The user has been saved: Abc, Def.', 'Flash.flash.0.message');

And the result in the cli is:

Failure asserting that null matches expected 'The user has been saved: Abc, Def.'.

**Debugging results:**

What I did notice is that when I remove all references to the key the message is still displayed and the test progressed a little further: Please see the code below:

```
// Users controller add action.
$this->Flash->success('The user has been saved', [
    //'key' => 'positive', // REMOVED KEY REF
    'params' => [
        'firstname' => $user->first_name,
        'lastname' => $user->last_name
     ]
]);

// Users Add View.
<?= $this->Flash->render() ?> // REMOVED KEY REF

    // In src/Template/Element/Flash/success.ctp
<div class="message-info success"> // REMOVED KEY REF
    <?= h($message) ?>: <?= h($params['firstname' ]) ?>, <?= h($params['lastname' ]) ?>.
</div>
```

And this still works, when a user is added the message with the parameters is displayed. The message displayed is:

The user has been saved: Abc, Def.

**The test result:**

The assertion in the test is constructed as detailed below:

$this->assertSession('The user has been saved: Abc, Def.', 'Flash.flash.0.message');

And the result in the cli is:

Failed asserting that two strings are equal:
---Expected
+++Actual
@@ @@
-'The user has been saved: Abc, Def.'
+'The user has been saved'

The parameters are not in the actual result and there is no colon (:) after saved?

**Summary**

Why did this test fail? Have I misinterpreted the documentation?

Cheers Z.

Comment: You are passing the result of a comparison (`false`) to the second argument of `assertSession()`.

Comment: @ndm, I've had a quick try at understanding by thinking the result of key == message (false) is being passed to 0? I still feel as though I'm quite a long way from understanding because of: 1. The key of the message is message so I'm not sure why that would be false? and 2. I shouldn't be passing that to the second argument which means that the comparison should be done somewhere else within that assertion? I've going out now but I'll have another go at furthering my understanding on Monday and thank you for the pointers, hopefully a few beers tonight might stimulate a few ideas :-).

Comment: What I'm saying is that what you are doing there is equal to passing `false` as the second argument, ie equal to calling `$this->assertSession('SUCCESS...', false);`. The second argument should be the path in the session data: **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-flash-messages**

Comment: @ndm, thanks for the extra pointers, to be honest I really can't understand why there would be a comparison there at all, surely defining a key value would be correct. (compare - what for?). I've also checked the public function assertSession in the api which clearly states that the construction of the assertion should contain, expected, path and the message. And the cookbook has an example of its construction when there isn't a key which I know works. The path is documented as: Flash.flash. I'll have another go with this new info and will post as soon as I hopefully get it working.

Comment: In my testing code, I've used `Flash.flash.0.message` as the key to check. I found this by debugging the contents of the session.